# Integrating rasa bot with multiple slack workspaces

Tags: slack, slack-api, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have built a rasa bot and integrated it with Slack as per the details provided in the Rasa doc. To share this bot on another Slack workspace, have implemented the Oauth and the bot is thus successfully installed in other workspaces as well.

**Issue**: The bot replies to the user in my development Workspace and not in any other. How can I enable this for multiple workspaces?